# How do I find the url for a brew tap?

Tags: homebrew

I added a [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) repository a long time ago with `brew tap`. I forgot the URL I used. `brew tap` doesn't list the URL:

```
$ brew tap
homebrew/core
shyiko/ktlint
foo/bar
```

How do I find the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the repository url by running:

```sh
brew tap-info foo/bar
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a tap `user/repo`, which is not on github, you can get the associated URL in two steps:

1) Go to the location of the tap.

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/[user]/homebrew-[repo]
```

2) Use git to check the remote repository

```
git remote -v
```

If the tap is on github you can simply make a substitution to get the URL:

```
https://github.com/[user]/homebrew-[repo]
```

Comment: My `foo/bar` URL is internal and doesn't rely on github.

Comment: Can you check my modified answer?

Comment: I'll check on Monday. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: You can also do this by using `brew tap-info foo/bar`

Comment: @Fhl That's a better answer! I'm going to make an answer out of it, but if you create your own, I'll delete mine and mark yours as correct.